# Simple UIViewAnimation for motion of an object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, game-physics, uiviewanimation

I wanted to develop a simple sample project where i have a player image, i'm having a logic for jumping of this player by simple UIViewAnimation now i want to make this **player object to run or walk** how can i achieve this **by normal UIViewAnimation** kind of stuff without using cocos2D or OpenGL.
Any help is appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi here is also one example project i hope this will help you to understand....

sample code [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5mat829nhfvd4j1/TiWLpW2YQi)

Comment: Thanks for the sample, i got the exact picture

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this using `UIViewAnimation` then you would have to create a number of images , known as **imageview animation** in which you would have to display each running image or walking image . This would give the impression that the image is walking or running. Then you would not be needing openGL or cocos2d.

BTW wat do u want to achieve ?

Comment: thanks for the reply,i'm just trying to prepare an article which focuses on basic objective c programming,here i want to show an example demo project where an object runs and jumps in a layout.

Comment: http://liehacker.dyndns.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/Picnic.zip . Maybe this link would help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The classic way to do this in 2d games is to make a spritesheet with the frames of the run animation for the player character. A spritesheet is a bitmap image made up of a grid of sub images. Each sub image holds a single frame of the run animation. To play the run animation forwards you need to create a list of the sub image to show for each frame number. The run animation will start at frame 0 and play at a given frame rate. You can create a timer which fires periodically at the end of each frame. When the timer fires, increment the frame number. Next use the frame number to index into the list of sub images to choose the correct sub image to show for the current animation frame. Invalidate the view containing the player image and when the system asks for the player view to be redrawn, draw the sub image for the current animation frame. Run animations repeat in a loop so long as the player is running. To loop the animation, you must check the value of the frame counter after it is incremented when the timer fires. If the frame counter value is equal to the number of animation frames for the run animation, reset the frame counter to zero. Then use the frame counter to index in the list of ordered sub images for the animation. The player view must also be moved in the direction in which the player runs each time that the animation timer fires. You calculate the distance by which to move the player view by multiplying the time between animation frames by the player speed.

To draw the current animation frame efficiently, store the sub images as NSValue objects containing a CGRect in an NSArray. Each CGRect is the sub rectangle containing an animation frame in the spritesheet. The sub rectangle can be used to clip the animation frame from the spritesheet so that only one animation frame is drawn when the spritesheet is drawn into the player view. The spritesheet must be drawn offset by the origin of the sub rectangle so that the top left of the animation frame coincides with the top left of the player view. The frame counter is used as the index to look up the current animation frame from the array.